# Background Task of iterating and updating large datasets in order

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to iterate around quite a large dataset of an entity in index order as a background task. (Number of entities approx 200,000+)

I am aware that the TaskQueue API along with possibly a background instance is the way to go, but I am hitting DataStoreUnavailable and timeout exceptions on occasion and what I'm looking for is a reliable way of iterating and updating in the background using the GAE APIs.

It is also very useful for me to know the progress of the iteration.

I am also aware of the experimental Java Map Reduce API but on first view to me this seems to be more of a parallel processing API rather than ordered. (Please correct me if I'm wrong. Java Map Reduce examples seem to be few and far between at the moment)

Are there any concrete examples or good patterns for doing this sort of work?

Answer (score 1):

Process only a limited number of entities in a job.

Start with a query as usual, but if the job request has a cursor parameter, apply it to the query. Then fetch only a fixed number of entities, instead of fetching all.

When the job is done, but there are more entities to process, retrieve the current query cursor, and schedule the same job again with the cursor as request parameter.

Comment: Yes, what you're describing is the obvious core elements for this type of work. But you shouldn't have to code all this yourself. There should be a framework for doing this safely and elegantly like MapReduce provides for a more parallel style of processing. If you're doing this sort of work all purely on top of the TaskQueue API then you have to handle all the caveats per implementation.

Comment: Indeed it would be nice to have a framework for all this. Unfortunately the obvious one (MapReduce) is still experimental and not very well documented.